# Get max value from table and group by with column having comma separated value with different order or having more values

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

I am having a table like this along with data

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
  `name` varchar(20),
  `ids` varchar(20),
  `value1` int,
   `value2` int
);

INSERT INTO temp(`name`,`ids`, `value1`, `value2`) values
  ('A', '1,2', 10, 11),
  ('A', '2,1', 12, 100),
   ('A', '1,2,3', 20, 1),
     ('B', '6', 30, 10)
```

I need to get the max value by **Name** along with **ids**

I am using the following query to get the max value.

```
select name, ids, max(value1) as value1, max(value2) as value2 
from temp
group by name,ids
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has been tagged as Sybase ASE, but the 'create table and 'insert' commands are invalid in ASE so not sure if this is an issue of an incorrect tag or the wrong 'create table' and 'insert' commands ... so, assuming this is for a Sybase ASE database:

I'm assuming the desired output is to display those rows where `value = max(value)`.

First we'll setup our test case:

```
create table mytab
(name  varchar(20)
,ids   varchar(20)
,value int)
go

insert into mytab (name,ids,value) values ('A', '1,2'  , 10)
insert into mytab (name,ids,value) values ('A', '2,1'  , 12)
insert into mytab (name,ids,value) values ('A', '1,2,3', 20)
insert into mytab (name,ids,value) values ('B', '6'    , 30)
go
```

Here's one possible solution:

```
select t.name, t.ids, t.value
from   mytab t
join   (select name,max(value) as maxvalue from mytab group by name) dt
on     t.name  = dt.name
and    t.value = dt.maxvalue
order by t.name
go

 name                 ids                  value
 -------------------- -------------------- -----------
 A                    1,2,3                         20
 B                    6                             30
```

The subquery/derived-table gives us the `max(value)` for each unique `name`.  The main query then joins these `name/max(value)` pairs back to the main table to give us the desired rows (ie, where `value = max(value)`).

Tested on ASE 15.7 SP138.

Comment: what if I am having a third column and need to find a max from that as well?